# Google Analytics E-Commerce Source

Tags: php, curl, google-analytics

I have the following problem and I can not deal with it. I am sending an url request at https://www.google-analytics.com/collect in this form:

```
$requestData = [
'cid' => $ orderData['cid'],
't' => 'item',
'ti' => $ order->getId (),
'in' => $ product['name'],
'ip' => $ product['amount'],
'iq' => 1,
'ic' => $ product['id'],
'iv' => 'Software',
'cu' => 'USD',
];
```

And everything is great, the transaction comes in, but instead of in the Source/Medium be the url of the store from where the transaction came in, it is "(direct)/(none)", I tried many ways and nothing :( I even combined the request under https://www.google-analytics.com/collect?utm_source=myWebsiteUrl but with zero effect, of course I send the data using CURL.

Maybe someone has an idea, or he had a similar problem and he solved it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for references to the Google Analytics Measurement Protocol.

Here's the documentation: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters#trafficsources

For your specific need, you need to add the Campaign Source (cs) and Campaign Medium (cm) parameters.

Thus your call will look like:

```
$requestData = [
'cid' => $ orderData['cid'],
't' => 'item',
'ti' => $ order->getId (),
'in' => $ product['name'],
'ip' => $ product['amount'],
'iq' => 1,
'ic' => $ product['id'],
'iv' => 'Software',
'cu' => 'USD',
'cm' => 'web',
'cs' => 'myweburl'
];
```

Also I do have to say, this is a very weird way of capturing e-commerce data. I would suggest a different solution instead.

Comment: What would you recommend instead of my current solution? I use AngularJs for the front, Symfony 3 backend, and I would like to send every purchase in the store to Analytics